# How to add fixed width and height constraints between windows content view and NSViewControllers View

Tags: macos, autolayout

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.rootVC = [[VZMConversationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VZMConversationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.rootVC.view];
    self.rootVC.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
/*
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.rootVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.window.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.rootVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.window.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];
//above 2 lines are not working
*/


}
```

Hey i am an iPhone developer trying to understand mac development, i have the above code and how to add constraints to first view controllers view so that controllers view resizes with the window. Can this be done in XIB?

Comment: Did you add the constraints to your window?

Comment: no to the windows content view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.rootVC = [[VZMConversationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VZMConversationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSView *rootView=self.rootVC.view;
    [rootView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:rootView];
    [[[self window] contentView] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[rootView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(rootView)]];
    [[[self window] contentView] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[rootView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(rootView)]];

}
```

This fixed the problem